# Automated script doesnt run if unitest is being used

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

the following is my code and when am clicking on run->python run in pydev, eclipse  it shows 'terminated 'in the console.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
chrome_driver = r'C:\Users\arkka.chatterjee\Desktop\chromedriver.exe'
class SearchTests(unittest.TestCase):

   def setUp(self):
      self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
      self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
      self.driver.maximize_window()
      self.driver.get("http://demo.magentocommerce.com/")
```

Comment: calling `implicitly_wait` is almost never a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setUp` is executed before each test.  In your `SearchTests` class, you have not defined any tests... so `setUp` will never run.  Add some tests!

for example:

```
class SearchTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("http://demo.magentocommerce.com/")

    def test_title(self):
       self.assert_equal(self.driver.title, 'Open Source | eCommerce | Magento')
```

Comment: wow ,thanks a lot for pointing it out , although i have been using selenium for python for around 2-3 months but this logic never came into my mind , thanks again for pointing it.Cheers!!

Comment: I tried doing the way you said , but still it did not work out , shows terminated as soon as i click on run , any other way of making it work??